# Find the Percentage from HackerRank

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

I am learning python by solving python module from HackerRank. This problem is [Find the Percentage](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/finding-the-percentage/problem?isFullScreen=false).

> You have a record of N students. Each record contains the student's
>   name, and their percent marks in Maths, Physics and Chemistry. The
>   marks can be floating values. The user enters some N integer followed
>   by the names and marks for N students. You are required to save the
>   record in a dictionary data type. The user then enters a student's
>   name. Output the average percentage marks obtained by that student,
>   correct to two decimal places.
>
> **Sample Input 0**
>
> ```
> 3
> Krishna 67 68 69 
> Arjun 70 98 63 
> Malika 52 56 60 
> Malika
> ```
>
> **Sample Output 0**
>
> ```
> 56.00
> ```

I need to improve this code by using better functions available in python.

```
def percentage(name):
    """
    Find percentage of marks of the student
    """

    marks = student_marks[name]
    total_marks = 0
    for mark in marks:
        total_marks += mark

    return format(total_marks/len(marks), '.2f')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    student_marks = {}
    for _ in range(n):
        name, *line = input().split()
        scores = list(map(float, line))
        student_marks[name] = scores
    query_name = input()
    print(percentage(query_name))
```

Comment: What do you need to improve about the code and why? Did you write this code? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, I wrote this and I am beginner in Python. I want to learn about other modules and functions which will help me to solve this problem.

Comment: (To the flagger: What gave rise to flag *not implemented or not working as intended*?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a beginner this is some good code. I would make some additional adjustments.

- One-line docstrings should be on one line, not over 3. And should end with a period.
- You should only pass the marks to `percentage` and not rely on a global `student_marks`.
- You can use `sum` to compute `total_marks`.
- I'm not a fan of having `format` in the `percentage` function.
- You should move all the main code into a main function, `if __name__ == '__main__':` should really only call this.
- It's more idiomatic to use comprehensions than `map`, even more so when you have `list(map(...))`.
- It's pretty rude to call a student a query. You can just use name.

```py
def percentage(marks):
    """Find percentage of marks of the student."""
    return sum(marks) / len(marks)


def main():
    """Main code."""
    n = int(input())
    student_marks = {}
    for _ in range(n):
        name, *scores = input().split()
        student_marks[name] = [float(score) for score in scores]
    name = input()
    result = percentage(student_marks[name])
    print(format(result, '.2f'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

- You can use `statistics.mean` rather than a custom made `percentage`.
- You can change the for loop into two comprehensions, a generator and dictionary comprehension.

  **Note**: I don't think comprehensions are better here, but are an 'as good' alternate.

```py
import statistics


def main():
    """Main code."""
    _marks = (input().split() for _ in range(int(input())))
    student_marks = {
        name: [float(score) for score in scores]
        for name, *scores in _marks
    }
    result = statistics.mean(student_marks[input()])
    print(format(result, '.2f'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `You can use statistics.mean` during input and have that average the value kept in the dict - as per problem statements, the individual scores are as important as the subjects they have been credited for.